# What is a good way of syncing a good sized AWS S3 bucket daily over to a non-AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, backup

I have a bucket that is about 20 TB in size (about 10 million objects) and every month it grows with about 0.5 TB.

I would like to back it up *outside* of AWS and would like a simple, safe and cost effective backup solution if possible. The idea is to sync the AWS bucket to another bucket in an S3 compatible service. Versions of objects do not need to be copied over (only the latest) and deletes should not be synced either. It could run once a night but optimally it should run more often.

I came up with a few different alternatives, would one of these (or another alternative) be the best bet for this to try first?

1. Simple S3 List Object call and use the modified date on the objects to compare with last backup date (have doubts about the performance of this alternative and perhaps transactional costs).
2. AWS CLI sync. Would it work with a non AWS S3 bucket and will it run (cost-)effectively on a bucket of this size?
3. Use inventory configuration in AWS S3 for the bucket. Write a custom application that iterates the generated inventory file and copies only new objects since last backup over to the backup bucket.
4. Use the event notifications feature in S3 to copy objects over to the backup bucket as they are created.
5. Other solution?

Comment: copying 20TB from s3 to outside of AWS is going to cost you almost $1800 in bandwidth cost alone according to the aws calculator ... Plus more each month for changes - just make sure you are aware of that before you pick a solution. BTW: S3 offers 11 9's of durability (i.e. 99.999999999%), are you certain you need an external copy?

Comment: What is your goal for backing up outside of S3? If it is to avoid accidental data loss, please note that Amazon S3 replicates your data to 3 different AZs. If you are wanting to avoid accidental deletion, you could replicate to an S3 bucket in a different AWS Account, and  use lower-cost _Infrequent Access_ or _Deep Archive_ storage. This would avoid Data Transfer costs.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan - that cost is acceptable and it should be a one time cost if we only transfer added files only in subsequent "backup syncs". The reason we want backup is to handle "black swans" or something like that - our AWS account is lost, a rogue employee is deleting everything or an application error (we will have MFA delete and versioning though on the bucket but we still need to permanently delete certain data so it opens up risks).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein as mentioned in the above comment to E.J. Brennan it´s a way for us to handle risks of dataloss. Should the very unlikely even occur that AWS is no longer operational (political risk, long term downtime etc) we would have an option to switch to the non-AWS bucket as a primary.